# Merge Sort Python Implementation ? What Is Wrong In The Implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, mergesort

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNtR5.png**strong text**

**This code is not working correctly. What's wrong in this code? How can it be fixed?**

```
       a=[2,5,8,7,1,9,6]
n=len(a)
temp=[0]*(n+1)
def mergesort(a,low,high):
    if low < high:
        mid=(low+high)/2
        mergesort(a,low,mid)
        mergesort(a,mid+1,high)
        combine(a,low,mid,high)
    print(a)    

def combine(a,low,mid,high):
    k=low
    i=low
    j=mid+1
    while i<=mid and j<=high:
        if a[i]<=a[j]:
            temp[k]=a[i]
            k=k+1
            i=i+1
        else:
            temp[k]=a[j]
            k+=1
            j+=1    
    while i<=mid:
        temp[k]=a[i]
        i+=1
        k+=1        
    while j<=high:
        temp[k]=a[j]
        j+=1
        k+=1
print('lets sort the array')
mergesort(a,0,n)
```

Comment: Hi there, please refrain from posting images of code, that includes the traceback. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: cool,can u help in solving it :)

Comment: `a` and `temp` are global variables. You may need `global a` and `global temp` under your `combine` function.

Comment: File "mergesort.py", line 20
    global temp[k]=a[i]
Adding Global Dosen't Works

Comment: You are getting the array limit exceeded error because you run your loop till j <= high, and j takes the value n in your first function call. But in an array of size n, j can reach only n-1. As for why the code still doesn't work, that's a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally, there are two problems: `n=len(a)` causes IndexError (change to `n=len(a)-1` respectively), and you've forgotten about copying from temp to the original array (add smth like the code below to the end of the `combine` routine:

```
for t in range(low, high+1):
    a[t] = temp[t]
```